# Cannot register clicks on iframe even with div overlay

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe

I've embedded an iframe on my website as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div style="position: relative; background-color: #8c9099; height: 300px; z-index: 2"
  (click)="setSelectedCourseElementFiddleUid()">
  <iframe width="100%" height="300px"
    style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 300px; display: inline-block"
    src="//jsfiddle.net/tutorpass/wLrk94mp/embedded/html,css,result/?accentColor=335eea"
    allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allowpaymentrequest [attr.frameborder]="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  setSelectedCourseElementFiddleUid() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

But the "click" itself, doesn't seem to register, even with the div overlay. Any idea on how I can fix this?

I've uploaded a Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jupmvt.

Comment: I see click event works fine after removing styles

Comment: What styles did you remove? Can you post a Stackblitz of what you have done?

Comment: here is my updated fork https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n74vpv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks, this only works with the edges of the iframe, not with the inside part of it. I'd like the click to register there as well?

Comment: Clicks on an iframe do not bubble upwards to outside the iframe I'm afraid..

Comment: Event dont bubble from iframe, if you want to cover iframe with a div - iframe next to div (not inside). If you want handle clicks inside iframe in parent window -- there are lots of examples.

Comment: you can use `pointer-events: none` on iframe to let the div capture click event, but then you cannot interact with iframe for sure. Maybe you could temporarily set `pointer-events: none` and switch back inside the click event handler.